# Bounding dimension of $H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q}}, (V_pE)^{\otimes n})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations, galois-cohomology

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, let $p$ be a prime of good reduction, $T_pE$ is its $p$-adic Tate module, $V_pE = T_pE\otimes \mathbb{Q}_p$, and $(V_pE)^{\otimes n}$ its $n$'th tensor power.

$H^1(G_{\mathbb{Q}}, (V_pE)^{\otimes n})$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}_p$ vector space. Is there a way to bound its dimension without using Fontaine-Mazur?